# New logout unusable with a touch-screen

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, ipad

I cannot use the Logout link on the new Profile popup on my iPad.

You can't hover a mouse on a touchscreen.

The general request is: All actions on floating popups should be available elsewhere too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* access that little pop-up by clicking the arrow *next to* your name.

No, it's *not* a very big target. But hey, you can always zoom in...

[image: CLIIIICK]

Comment: right, got it. New ipad.

Comment: In general, I think the UI for the stack sites should take touch-screens into consideration.  The UI elements are often a bit small for touch and sometimes rely on mouse cursor hovering such as voting up this comment.  Go ahead, I dare you to try to vote up this comment on a touch screen device (using touch).  :-)

Comment: @Keith - tap once next to the comment to show the voting controls, tap again to use them.